# Как задать template и labelOptions для Select2?

Tags: php, yii2, yii, select2, kartik

Как в Select2 в Yii 2 задать свои template и labelOptions? Для обычного поля это можно сделать через field->labelOptions и field->template. А как это сделать для Select2?

```
$form->field($model, 'test',[
    'labelOptions' => ['style' => 'display:none !important;'],
    'template' => '{label}{input}{error}'])
    ->radioButtonGroup($data, ['itemOptions' => ['class' => 'btn btn-default', 'style' => 'display:none !important;']
]); ?>
```

Select2, про который идет речь: https://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам задал и вопрос и сам ответил, причем еще в самом вопросе. Достаточно было сделать как в примере с вопроса - задать field->template и field->labelOptions по необходимости:

```
$form->field($model, 'test', [
    'template' => '{label}{input}{error}'
])->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => $data,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]);
```